# I have created Progressbar programmatically, now how can i keep it center of screen and ontop of other views when made visible inside linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created Progressbar programmatically, now how can i keep it at the center of screen and ontop of other views when made visible inside linearlayout ?

Comment: Add the layout file where you would place your custom `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `RelativeLayout` instead of the `LinearLayout` and add attributes to your `ProgressBar`: `centerInParent` = true.

Covering up views under another view can only be done in `RelativeLayout` (or `FrameLayout`, but more tricky)

Comment: so you are saying that there is no way i can do this in a LinearLayout ?

Comment: You could go over all the children of the LinearLayout, making them all visibility=gone, and adding the ProgressBar, but it seems very wasteful to me. Have you considered simply popping up a dialog w/ a ProgressBar?

Comment: I understand, i just wanted to know if there is a way to do it, i am surprised that there is no layout_gravity for progressbar in linearlayout. :)